# How to create a new private branch in P4 (perforce) from an existing one?

Tags: branch, p4v, perforce-branch-spec

I am using P4V. I need to create a new private branch from an existing project repository. How can i do this in P4V?

From a help file, I got the following steps:

1. Create a branch Specification for the files you want to keep in private branch
   In P4 it could be done through File-->New-->Branch Specification
2. Create a new Workspace and in the workspace view specify the source as the private branch folders
3. Integrate the files using the branch specification from the new workspace

   Right click on the root of the tree in the left side

   Click the Integrage option and using branch specification tab integrate using the branch specification created in step1
4. Resolve and do the checkin
   This will create new folders in the Depot also

Edit:
Step 1 done. Thanks to msKing
How to create a new workspace?

Answer (score 1):

In P4v Branch Specification is named as  'Branch Mapping...'. You can also use Ctrl+3 to open the Branch Mappings tab. Right click in the tab and create the new BranchSpec.

Comment: Thats where you create the BranchSpec, just fill the fields like Branch Mapping and View.  In view give //<From Branch Path>/... //<To Branch Path>/...